# Login post request generates error

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to implement a simple login system with angular. Currently if I try to login with the correct details I can successfully obtain an access token and store it to local storage.

Attempting to login with wrong details however creates a 401 unauthorised error in response to the post request. Is there another way to test for login failure than looking for parameters in the response like I am doing now?

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  public token: string;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        this.token = currentUser && currentUser.id;
   }

   public login(username:string, password:string){
    return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/login', {username:username, password:password})
      .map((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        let token = res.id ;
        let id = res.userId ;
        // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
        if (token) {
          this.token = token;
            // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: username, token: token, id:id }));
            // return true to indicate successful login
            return true;
        } else {
            // return false to indicate failed login
            return false;
        }
    });
  }
```

**login-form.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AlertService } from '../../_services/alert.service';
import { AuthService } from '../../_services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-form',
  templateUrl: './login-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-form.component.css'],
  providers: [AuthService, AlertService]
})

export class LoginFormComponent implements OnInit {
  model: any = {};
  loading = false;
  error = '';
  returnUrl: string;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private alertService: AlertService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  login() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.authService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
        .subscribe(result => {
            console.log(result);
            if (result==true) {
                this.loading = false;
                //this.router.navigate(['/']);
                this.alertService.success('Success', true);
            } else {
                this.error = 'Username or password is incorrect';
                this.loading = false;
            }
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd display a red error message on the screen, exactly as you seem to be doing with `this.error` field (show it on the screen on top of the form if it's set, reset it on resubmit).

Comment: It is not working. The post request itself generates the 401 error

Answer (score 1):

you can catch a error

**Service**

```
return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/login', {username:username, password:password})
          .map((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            let token = res.id ;
            let id = res.userId ;
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            if (token) {
              this.token = token;
                // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: username, token: token, id:id }));
                // return true to indicate successful login
                return true;
            } else {
                // return false to indicate failed login
                return false;
            }
        }).catch((error: Response) => {
        return Observable.throw(error.json());
    });
```

**Component**

```
   login() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.authService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
            .subscribe(result => {
                console.log(result);
                if (result==true) {
                    this.loading = false;
                    //this.router.navigate(['/']);
                    this.alertService.success('Success', true);
                } else {
                    this.error = 'Username or password is incorrect';
                    this.loading = false;
                }
            },(error)=>{
                   this.error = error.message?error.message:'Username or password is incorrect';
                    this.loading = false;
      }
});
```

Comment: Is it good practice to use the error condition in subscribe like this? Seems to be working but I still see a error in the console.